# How can I cast TextEditingController to String in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, textformfield

I'm retrieving some data from Firestore like this:

```
 String _fName;

  Future<dynamic>_retrieveData() async{
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    await Firestore.instance.collection("tryingdata").document(firebaseUser.uid).snapshots().listen((DocumentSnapshot doc) async{
      Map<String, dynamic> document = doc.data;
      setState((){
        _fName = document['firstName'];
      });
      print(_fName);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _retrieveData();
  }
```

and I want to have an initialValue in my TextFormField, but I must use controller instead of initialValue, but controller must be a TextEditingController variable. But I retrieve String from database. I want the value from the database to be shown in the TextFormField as initial value.
I'm getting the following error: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextEditingController'.

```
TextFormField(
              controller: _fName,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            ),
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your controller:

```
var controller = TextEditingController();
```

And then once you get the string, just do

```
setState(() => controller.text = _fName);
```

Comment: my StringValue is _fName which is retrieved from database, but I can't do  var controller = TextEditingController(text: _fName); 
it's telling me The instance member '_fName' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
```

you could modify it after creating an object of TextEditingController using the text setter like this:

```
controller.text = "my initial value";
```

you have to use set state tho to see the change

Comment: I can assign "some string" and it's working fine but I want to assign _fName which is retrieved from my database as String. When I do var controller = TextEditingController(text: _fName); it's telling me The instance member '_fName' can't be accessed in an initializer.